# How to compare text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, compare, match

I have the following code:

```
var nowa = [];      
var tab = [{'material':'221214', 'item':'SPRITE 0,33LX24PUS', 'quantity':'2', 'jedn':'CS'}];

$.each(tab, function(index, w) {

 if(($.inArray(w.material, nowa)) == -1){

  nowa.push(w.material);

   if(w.item == '0,33')
    rodzaj = 'can';

   if(w.item == '0.5')
    rodzaj = 'pet';

  $('table.new').append('<tr class="'+w.material+'" id="'+rodzaj+'"><td>'+w.material+'</td><td>'+w.item+'</td><td class="qq">'+w.quantity+'</td><td>'+w.jedn+'</td></tr>');

 }
});//each
```

How to compare w.item with other text in this case?

Because this:

```
if(w.item == '0,33')
rodzaj = 'can';
```

is not working.

w.item values can be:
0,5
0.5
0.33
1,0
1.5
2,5
and other.

Comment: Do you have list of values that w.item could have? (0,5 0.5 0.33 1,0 1.5 2,5 and the values for rodzaj?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
w.item.search('0,33')
```

So your comparison will look like

```
if(w.item.search('0.33') >= 0) {
  roadzaj = 'can';
}
```

Read more about **[.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)**

> If search become successful, `search()` returns the index of the
>   searched element inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1.

Comment: Careful, though, because w.item.search returns an integer value, not a boolean. So you'd have to do something like `w.item.search('0,33') > -1`